# Trying to Deploy a PCF Spring Boot App which requires a static IP

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have an application that uses spring boot for a backend and Vue.js as a front end. I have packaged the app into a jar file and deployed to PCF with ease. The problem is the application uses API Keys from https://developer.clashroyale.com/#/getting-started ...these keys require you to input the IP Address that will be used...

Obviously my key will not work unless I give the correct IP address, so how do I retrieve the IP Address for my PCF application so I can generate the proper API Key?

Also, the documentation says that the IP will change with every deployment of my application... Which prompts the question :

Is it impossible to use API Keys that require static IP Addresses with PCF applications?

I have deployed this same application to amazon AWS and it worked because I have a static IP Address that I can use to register a key. I prefer to use PCF, but am having trouble setting it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to use that API on the PCF platform. Every time you either `cf restage` or anything to cause the container to be rebuilt/redeployed, the IP will change.

So in short yes, it's impossible: https://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/external-ips.html

Answer (score 1):

Your app will be run on any number of Diego Cells, which all have different IP addresses. There are a couple ways that traffic can leave your app and the Cell.

In some cases, outbound traffic may go through a NAT, in which case the number of possible IPs may be small and the IPs may not change often (or at all). In other cases, traffic may leave directly from the Diego Cell on which your application is running. In this case, there's a lot more IPs & the IPs will change any time your app is restarted.

If you're talking about some general installation of Cloud Foundry, it will depend on how the operators for that environment have set up the traffic to flow so you'd need to confirm with your operator to be certain.

If you're talking about Pivotal Web Services, outbound traffic will originate from the IP of the Cell on which your app is running. See the link in Francisco's post.

---

Having said all that, there's a hack that you can use to work around the behavior above. Route your traffic through a proxy. Traffic coming out of the proxy can be made to have a fixed IP address.

On PWS, there is a service in the marketplace available to do exactly this. It's called QuotaGuard.

https://docs.run.pivotal.io/marketplace/services/quotaguard.html

You don't have to use that service though, you could use any other service provider or you could even set up your own proxy. I would recommend using a service unless you know exactly what you are doing though. Setting up & securing a proxy is not trivial and an improperly secured proxy is bad not just for you as the owner but the whole Internet.